# Underline left floating divs

Tags: html, css

The goal is to achieve this effect without adding any html tag (div, hr, ...) each three divs.

That mean through **css only**.

What I thought would be an idea was to set the line-height to 150px and underlining it.
But it doesn't seem to produce the result.

[image: underlined divs]

The css I use for now produces the result without the underline:

```
.projectContainer{
    /*line-height:150px;
    text-decoration:underline;*/
}
.projectBlock{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
}
.projectImage{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:200px;
    height:112px;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:0% 50%; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.projectCaptcha{
    position:absolute;
    top:113px;
    left:0px;
    width:200px;
    height:88px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

And the html is a list of:

```
<div class="projectBlock">
    <div class="projectImage" style='background-image:url(...)'></div>
    <div class="projectCaptcha">MUSÉE RATH, GENEVE MAURICE BRAILLARD</div>
</div>
```

in a:

```
<div class="projectContainer">
     ...
</div>
```

If the comment is removed the result is not what was planed:

[image: screwed css]

Thank you and sorry for my english!

Comment: May be just `border-bottom: 1px solid` for `.projectBlock` gives the effect you need? It looks that there are no gaps between blocks, so their borders will appear as the one solid line.

Comment: Without HTML mark up it is very difficult to debug. Provide the mark up.

Comment: How come your image and text are all position absolute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you could just add a `border-bottom` to `.projectBlock`.

```
.projectBlock {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  ...
}
```

You might need to add some margin and padding above and below to get the spacing correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the border property, and if you only want to select certain divs use nth-child(an+b) pseudo-class.

Comment: Yes, I like your solution very much, but I won't use it because of the compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2tzW/)
I think you need to clear the floats for each container.

```
.projectContainer{
    height:150px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #777;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong but the impression I got was that there was only one project container.